# Trouble with transitioning background Image with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

### Edit

I figured out that it is actually fading out, it just removes the background image before it starts the fade so I can't see it...duh. I just removed the `.css('background','')` so it fades out now. Some of my css styles still are not affecting it though. Somehow it is getting a `background-repeat: initial;` put on it that is overriding the class styles. Is this because the js is acting on its styling?

---

Original:

I have read through some other questions on here and they helped me get this far, but I am still not seeing a solution.

I am having trouble with fading background images on hover. I am storing image urls as data attributes of a list of links. When you hover on the link, the background of another div is set to be the respective image through jquery.

I have gotten the background image to be assigned, added a class to make it visible. It works fading in, but not out. When I manually remove the visibility class while in chrome dev tools it fades out as expected, but not when the jquery removes it. other "background-" css styles are not working either unless I add an !Important. I cannot tell what is overriding them though.

### **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2v9sa4h/4/)**

### HTML

```
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="item" data-img="http://goo.gl/hbKhMi">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item" data-img="http://goo.gl/7p0Kki">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item" data-img="http://goo.gl/EHW4Xs">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.backdrop {
    width:450px;
    height:400px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.75s;
    transition: opacity 0.75s;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.visable{
      opacity:1;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.backdrop').css('background','url('+$(this).data("img")+')').addClass('visable');
    });
    $('.item').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.backdrop').css('background', '').removeClass('visable');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a bit your JS code, using `backgroundImage` instead `background` to set the images, and when `mouseleave`, don't remove the `backgroundImage`, only the class. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.backdrop').css('backgroundImage','url('+$(this).data("img")+')').addClass('visable');
    });
    $('.item').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.backdrop').removeClass('visable');
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/y2v9sa4h/8/